# f2py failed in converting to C/Fortran array

Tags: python, fortran, f2py

I tried to write a Fortran wrapper to Python and got `failed in converting hidden c of test.wrap to C/Fortran array`.   May I know how to fix it? Here is the `python` part, as `warp.py`

```
import numpy as np

A = np.random.random((5,5))
B = np.random.random((5,5))
C = np.zeros((5, 5))

A = np.asfortranarray(A)
B = np.asfortranarray(B)
C = np.asfortranarray(C)

test.wrap(A, B)
print(C[0,0])
```

here is the `Fortran` part, called `test.f90`. I used `python -m numpy.f2py -c  --f90flags='-O3'  -m test test.f90`.

```
subroutine wrap(A, B, C)
    implicit none
    real, intent(in) :: A(:, :), B(:, :)
    real, intent(out) :: C(:, :)
    integer :: m, n, p

    m = size(A, 1)
    n = size(A, 2)
    p = size(B, 2)
    
    if (n /= size(B, 1)) then
        print *, "Error: Incompatible dimensions for matrix multiplication"
        return
    end if

    C = matmul(A, B)
end
```

Full error message

```
ValueError: failed to create intent(cache|hide)|optional array -- must have defined dimensions, but dims[0] = -1

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "wrap.py", line 12, in <module>
    test.wrap(A, B)
ValueError: failed in converting hidden `c' of test.wrap to C/Fortran array
```

Comment: Was there anything more in the error output? The output of f2py is usually much richer. Show the full output. Or does the message appear when running the Python code? Which line exactly?

Comment: Updated error message.

Comment: Well, the first line seems to be the more relevant one, not the first one you posted originally. Since `C` is not pased to the f2py function, f2py needs to know how big `C` should be created. You did not give f2py such information and in Fortran you only have `(:,:)`.

Comment: Note that your `C = np.zeros((5, 5))` is irrelevant, it does not appear in the call to `test.wrap`. I am not sure if just doing `C = test.wrap(A, B)` would suffice, but you can try it.

Comment: using `C = test.wrap(A, B)` does not work. `ValueError: failed to create intent(cache|hide)|optional array -- must have defined dimensions, but dims[0] = -1

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "wrap.py", line 12, in <module>
    test.wrap(A, B)
ValueError: failed in converting hidden `c' of test.wrap to C/Fortran array` I got it work by changing fortran part from `out` to `inout`, specify python part to float 32, will write an answer

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the comment from Vladimir F Героям слава. Change the Fortran part into

```
subroutine wrap(A, B, C)
    implicit none
    real, intent(in) :: A(:, :), B(:, :)
    real, intent(inout) :: C(:, :)
    integer :: m, n, p

    m = size(A, 1)
    n = size(A, 2)
    p = size(B, 2)
    
    if (n /= size(B, 1)) then
        print *, "Error: Incompatible dimensions for matrix multiplication"
        return
    end if

    C = matmul(A, B)
end
```

and python part into

```
import numpy as np
import test

A = np.random.random((5,5)).astype(np.float32)
B = np.random.random((5,5)).astype(np.float32)
C = np.zeros((5, 5), dtype=np.float32)

A = np.asfortranarray(A)
B = np.asfortranarray(B)
C = np.asfortranarray(C)

test.wrap(A, B, C)
print("Fortran result:")
print(C)

# Cross-check with numpy.einsum
C_check = np.einsum('ij,jk->ik', A, B)
print("Numpy einsum result:")
print(C_check)

# Compare the two results
print("Are the results equal?")
print(np.allclose(C, C_check))
```

it works