# matmul_r8_avx2: failed. in increasing dimension with python f2py

Tags: python, numpy, fortran, f2py

I am using Fortran wrapper `f2py`. It works previously with `n=5~30` for matrix multiplication ([f2py failed in converting to C/Fortran array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76139269/f2py-failed-in-converting-to-c-fortran-array)).

When I increase to `50`, it tells me problem `python: /home/rdonnelly/mc/conda-bld/compilers_linux-64_1534627447954/work/.build/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/src/gcc/libgfortran/generated/matmul_r8.c:642: matmul_r8_avx2: Assertion` ((a)->dtype & 0x07) == 2 || ((b)->dtype & 0x07) == 2' failed.
Aborted (core dumped)`.

Here is the python part `test-f2py.py`

```
import numpy as np
import test

dim_n = 50
A = np.random.random((dim_n, dim_n))
B = np.random.random((dim_n, dim_n))
C = np.zeros((dim_n, dim_n))

A = np.asfortranarray(A)
B = np.asfortranarray(B)
C = np.asfortranarray(C)

test.wrap(A, B, C)
print("Fortran result:")
#print(C)

# Cross-check with numpy.einsum
C_check = np.einsum('ij,jk->ik', A, B)
print("Numpy einsum result:")
#print(C_check)

# Compare the two results
print("Are the results equal?")
print(np.allclose(C, C_check))
```

fortran part, `test.f90`, run by `python -m numpy.f2py -c  --f90flags='-O3'  -m test test.f90`

```
!f2py dp selected_real_kind(15, 307)
subroutine wrap(A, B, C)
    real(kind=8), intent(in) :: A(:, :), B(:, :)
    real(kind=8), intent(inout) :: C(:, :)
    integer :: m, n, p

    m = size(A, 1)
    n = size(A, 2)
    p = size(B, 2)
    
    if (n /= size(B, 1)) then
        print *, "Error: Incompatible dimensions for matrix multiplication"
        return
    end if

    C = matmul(A, B)
end subroutine wrap
```

if I run the python code, e.g., `python test-f2py.py` I got

```
python: /home/rdonnelly/mc/conda-bld/compilers_linux-64_1534627447954/work/.build/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/src/gcc/libgfortran/generated/matmul_r8.c:642: matmul_r8_avx2: Assertion `((a)->dtype & 0x07) == 2 || ((b)->dtype & 0x07) == 2' failed.
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Comment: Works fine for me up to n=5000 (didn't care to try bigger than that).

Comment: Works for me too, I tested it until 5000, with gfortran on mac M1

Comment: I tested on intel i7 laptop. Maybe I should try to upgrade `f2py`

Comment: Upgrade numpy and gfortran does not help. I figured out a walk around. If I use `f2py` instead of `numpy.f2py`, it tells me `/usr/include/python3.8/pyconfig.h:3:12: fatal error: x86_64-linux-gnu/python3.8/pyconfig.h: No such file or directory
 #  include <x86_64-linux-gnu/python3.8/pyconfig.h>`. Then I switched to python 3.9 env in coda, it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrade `numpy` and `gfortran` does not help. I figured out a walk around. If I use `f2py` instead of `numpy.f2py`, it tells me

```
/usr/include/python3.8/pyconfig.h:3:12: fatal error: x86_64-linux-gnu/python3.8/pyconfig.h: No such file or directory  #  include <x86_64-linux-gnu/python3.8/pyconfig.h>
```

Then I switched to python 3.9 env in coda, it works